# Struts2 + Freemarker + DisplayTag: how to make it work

Tags: struts2, freemarker, displaytag

I am currently upgrading our application from Webwork to Struts2. Today I run into strange error: displayTag stopped working after the upgrade.

This is a snipped from my FTL file:

```
<#assign display=JspTaglibs["http://displaytag.sf.net"]>

<@s.set name="entries" value="historyEntries" scope="page"/>

<@display.table class="data" name="pageScope.entries" sort="list" 
      pagesize=30 id="entry" defaultsort=5 defaultorder="descending">
  <@display.column property="folderName" title="Folder" sortable=true/>
</@display.table>
```

The error I get is:

```
freemarker.template.TemplateModelException:   
javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: Exception:   
[.LookupUtil] Error looking up property "folderName" 
in object type "freemarker.template.SimpleSequence". 
Cause: Unknown property 'folderName'
```

Standard struts tags are working correctly, I have `JspSupportServlet` added in my configuration. Any idead why this isn't working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to solve this (not sure if it the only way or if it is the best, worked for me though).

The root of the problem was that `freemarker.template.SimpleSequence` does not out-of-the-box implement any standard Collections API, it is not a Collection, Enumerable etc.

In order to solve this I created custom `FreemarkerManager` and provided custom `BeansWrapper`:

```
@Override
protected BeansWrapper getObjectWrapper() {
    BeansWrapper wrapper = super.getObjectWrapper();
    class CustomBeansWrapper extends BeansWrapper {
        private BeansWrapper internalWrapper;

        public Xp2BeansWrapper(BeansWrapper wrapper) {
            this.internalWrapper = wrapper;
        }

        //delegate methods


        public TemplateModel wrap(Object object) throws TemplateModelException {
            TemplateModel model = internalWrapper.wrap(object);
            if (model instanceof SimpleSequence) {
                class SimpleSequenceWithIterator extends SimpleSequence {
                    private SimpleSequence internalSequence;
                    public SimpleSequenceWithIterator(SimpleSequence sequence) {
                        this.internalSequence = sequence;
                    }

                    //delegate methods

                    //IteratorUtils from Apache Commons is used internally 
                    //by DisplayTag library, it can use public iterator() method
                    public Iterator iterator() throws TemplateModelException {
                        return toList().iterator();
                    }

                }
                return new SimpleSequenceWithIterator((SimpleSequence) model);
            }
            return model;
        }


    }
    return new CustomBeansWrapper(wrapper);

}
```

Now I just needed to change one setting in `struts.properties`:

```
struts.freemarker.manager.classname=xyz.CustomFreemarkerManager
```

Comment: the value of the settings parameter object_wrapper can be set to
freemarker.ext.beans.BeansWrapper to ensure the simple wrapper is not used

Answer (score 0):

You can also certify if your deployment copy all dependecies to WEB-INF/lib. TaglibFactory searches every TLD under /META-INF/ inside jar there.

Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/37092269/1113510