# Spring-Boot with JSP Tag Libs in embedded Tomcat

Tags: spring-boot, freemarker, jsp-tags, embedded-tomcat-8

I am currently migrating a Spring MVC Webapp (xml-config to java-config, tomcat to embedded tomcat via spring-boot).

The webapp uses freemarker as templating engine and JSP Taglibs. Now when I call a freemarker page I get the following error:

```
freemarker.ext.jsp.TaglibFactory$TaglibGettingException: 
No TLD was found for the "http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" JSP taglib URI. (TLD-s are searched according the JSP 2.2 specification. In development- and embedded-servlet-container setups you may also need the "MetaInfTldSources" and "ClasspathTlds" freemarker.ext.servlet.FreemarkerServlet init-params or the similar system properites.)
```

The freemarker-header.ftl begins with following snippet:

```
<#assign form=JspTaglibs["http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"]>
<#assign core=JspTaglibs["http://java.sun.com/jstl/core"]>
<#assign spring=JspTaglibs["http://www.springframework.org/tags"]>
<#assign osc=JspTaglibs["/WEB-INF/osc.tld"]>
```

I did not find any usable search results for MetaInfTldSources and ClasspathTlds. Any one solved this problem before?

KR
Habib

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring Boot doesn't support the use of JSP taglibs with Freemarker out of the box. There's an [open enhancement request](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/907) that you might be interested in. It contains a link to a possible workaround where you configure `FreemarkerConfigurer`'s tag lib factory with some additional TLDs to be loaded from the classpath:

```
freeMarkerConfigurer.getTaglibFactory().setClasspathTlds(…);
```

Comment: Hi, I tried that, but it does not work... Current workaround is putting the tlds from the JARs to webapp/META-INF folder. But that only works when starting the application with spring-boot:run command. Running the Application via standard main Application class in IntelliJ leads to the same result, that the app does not find the tld files... :-(

Answer (score 2):

This really should be built-in.

First, disable the built in `FreeMarkerAutoConfiguration` on your `Application`:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = {FreeMarkerAutoConfiguration.class})
public class Application extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    ...
]
```

Then add this custom configuration:

(adapted from https://github.com/isopov/fan/blob/master/fan-web/src/main/java/com/sopovs/moradanen/fan/WebApplicationConfiguration.java; Added an `ObjectWrapper` to the `TaglibFactory` and removed the `addResourceHandlers()` override)

```
import freemarker.cache.ClassTemplateLoader;
import freemarker.ext.jsp.TaglibFactory;
import freemarker.template.TemplateException;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.InterceptorRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.SessionLocaleResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.freemarker.FreeMarkerConfig;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.freemarker.FreeMarkerConfigurer;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.freemarker.FreeMarkerViewResolver;

import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationHandler;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.lang.reflect.Proxy;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.Properties;

@Configuration
public class CustomFreemarkerConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {


    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        LocaleChangeInterceptor localeChangeInterceptor = new LocaleChangeInterceptor();
        localeChangeInterceptor.setParamName("lang");
        registry.addInterceptor(localeChangeInterceptor);
    }

    @Bean
    public ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource() {
        ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();
        messageSource.setBasename("classpath:messages");
        messageSource.setFallbackToSystemLocale(false);
        messageSource.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
        return messageSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public SessionLocaleResolver localeResolver() {
        SessionLocaleResolver localeResolver = new SessionLocaleResolver();
        localeResolver.setDefaultLocale(Locale.ENGLISH);
        return localeResolver;
    }

    @Bean
    @Autowired
    public freemarker.template.Configuration freeMarkerConfig(ServletContext servletContext) throws IOException,
            TemplateException {
        FreeMarkerConfigurer freemarkerConfig = configFreeMarkerConfigurer(servletContext);
        return freemarkerConfig.getConfiguration();
    }

    @Bean
    @Autowired
    public TaglibFactory taglibFactory(ServletContext servletContext) throws IOException, TemplateException {
        FreeMarkerConfigurer freemarkerConfig = configFreeMarkerConfigurer(servletContext);
        TaglibFactory taglibFactory = freemarkerConfig.getTaglibFactory();
        taglibFactory.setObjectWrapper(freemarker.template.Configuration.getDefaultObjectWrapper(freemarker.template.Configuration.getVersion()));
        return taglibFactory;
    }

    @Autowired
    @Bean
    public FreeMarkerConfig springFreeMarkerConfig(ServletContext servletContext) throws IOException, TemplateException {
        return new MyFreeMarkerConfig(freeMarkerConfig(servletContext), taglibFactory(servletContext));
    }

    private static FreeMarkerConfigurer configFreeMarkerConfigurer(ServletContext servletContext) throws IOException,
            TemplateException {
        FreeMarkerConfigurer freemarkerConfig = new FreeMarkerConfigurer();
        freemarkerConfig
                .setPreTemplateLoaders(new ClassTemplateLoader(CustomFreemarkerConfiguration.class, "/templates/"));
        ServletContext servletContextProxy = (ServletContext) Proxy.newProxyInstance(
                ServletContextResourceHandler.class.getClassLoader(),
                new Class<?>[] { ServletContext.class },
                new ServletContextResourceHandler(servletContext));
        freemarkerConfig.setServletContext(servletContextProxy);
        Properties settings = new Properties();
        settings.put("default_encoding", "UTF-8");
        freemarkerConfig.setFreemarkerSettings(settings);
        freemarkerConfig.afterPropertiesSet();
        return freemarkerConfig;
    }

    @Bean
    public FreeMarkerViewResolver viewResolver() {
        FreeMarkerViewResolver viewResolver = new FreeMarkerViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setCache(false);
        viewResolver.setSuffix(".ftl");
        viewResolver.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        return viewResolver;
    }


    private static class ServletContextResourceHandler implements InvocationHandler
    {

        private final ServletContext target;

        private ServletContextResourceHandler(ServletContext target) {
            this.target = target;
        }

        @Override
        public Object invoke(Object proxy, Method method, Object[] args) throws Throwable {
            if ("getResourceAsStream".equals(method.getName())) {
                Object result = method.invoke(target, args);
                if (result == null) {
                    result = CustomFreemarkerConfiguration.class.getResourceAsStream((String) args[0]);
                }
                return result;
            } else if ("getResource".equals(method.getName())) {
                Object result = method.invoke(target, args);
                if (result == null) {
                    result = CustomFreemarkerConfiguration.class.getResource((String) args[0]);
                }
                return result;
            }

            return method.invoke(target, args);
        }
    }

    private static class MyFreeMarkerConfig implements FreeMarkerConfig {

        private final freemarker.template.Configuration configuration;
        private final TaglibFactory taglibFactory;

        private MyFreeMarkerConfig(freemarker.template.Configuration configuration, TaglibFactory taglibFactory) {
            this.configuration = configuration;
            this.taglibFactory = taglibFactory;
        }

        @Override
        public freemarker.template.Configuration getConfiguration() {
            return configuration;
        }

        @Override
        public TaglibFactory getTaglibFactory() {
            return taglibFactory;
        }
    }
}
```

Add the following to your `pom.xml`:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Then you can load in your template:

```
<#assign s=JspTaglibs["/META-INF/spring.tld"] />

<a href="${s.mvcUrl("IC#index").build()}">Home</a>
```

Comment: Great answer, totally solves the problem. I personally was trying to add spring-security support to my freemarker files and after adding this CustomFreemarkerConfiguration all I had to do to make this work was  <#assign security=JspTaglibs["/security.tld"] />.

Answer (score 2):

It is actually an easy task if you know how to do it. All you need is already embedded into FreeMarker, for instance it is `TaglibFactory.ClasspathMetaInfTldSource` class. I spend several hours to investigate that problem, so I want to share a solution.

I implemented it as `BeanPostProcessor` because now there is no way to set `TaglibFactory` before `FreeMarkerConfigurer` bean is initialized.

```
import freemarker.ext.jsp.TaglibFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.BeansException;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanPostProcessor;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.freemarker.FreeMarkerConfigurer;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

/**
 * A {@link BeanPostProcessor} that enhances {@link FreeMarkerConfigurer} bean, adding
 * {@link freemarker.ext.jsp.TaglibFactory.ClasspathMetaInfTldSource} to {@code metaInfTldSources}
 * of {@link TaglibFactory}, containing in corresponding {@link FreeMarkerConfigurer} bean.
 *
 * <p>
 * This allows JSP Taglibs ({@code *.tld} files) to be found in classpath ({@code /META-INF/*.tld}) in opposition
 * to default FreeMarker behaviour, where it searches them only in ServletContext, which doesn't work
 * when we run in embedded servlet container like {@code tomcat-embed}.
 *
 * @author Ruslan Stelmachenko
 * @since 20.02.2019
 */
@Component
public class JspTagLibsFreeMarkerConfigurerBeanPostProcessor implements BeanPostProcessor {

    @Override
    public Object postProcessAfterInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) throws BeansException {
        if (bean instanceof FreeMarkerConfigurer) {
            FreeMarkerConfigurer freeMarkerConfigurer = (FreeMarkerConfigurer) bean;
            TaglibFactory taglibFactory = freeMarkerConfigurer.getTaglibFactory();

            TaglibFactory.ClasspathMetaInfTldSource classpathMetaInfTldSource =
                    new TaglibFactory.ClasspathMetaInfTldSource(Pattern.compile(".*"));

            taglibFactory.setMetaInfTldSources(Arrays.asList(classpathMetaInfTldSource));
//            taglibFactory.setClasspathTlds(Arrays.asList("/META-INF/tld/common.tld"));
        }
        return bean;
    }
}
```

The only restriction is that `*.tld` files must have `<uri>` xml tag inside. All standard spring/spring-security TLDs have it. And also these files must be inside `META-INF` folder of classpath, like `META-INF/mytaglib.tld`. All standard spring/spring-security TLDs are also follow this convention.

Commented line is just for example of how you can add "custom" paths of `*.tld` files if for some reason you can't place them into standard location (maybe some external jar, which doesn't follow the convention). It can be extended to some sort of classpath scanning, searching for all `*.tld` files and adding them into `classpathTlds`. But usually it is just doesn't required if your TLDs follow JSP conventions to be placed inside `META-INF` directory.

I have tested this in my FreeMarker template and it works:

```
<#assign common = JspTaglibs["http://my-custom-tag-library/tags"]>
<#assign security = JspTaglibs["http://www.springframework.org/security/tags"]>
<#assign form = JspTaglibs["http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"]>
<#assign spring = JspTaglibs["http://www.springframework.org/tags"]>
```

For custom tag ("http://my-custom-tag-library/tags") to work, it must be `*.tld` file in `src/main/resources/META-INF/some.tld` and it must contain the `<uri>` xml tag, like `<uri>http://my-custom-tag-library/tags</uri>`. It will be found by FreeMarker then.

I hope it helps someone to save several hours to find "right" solution for this problem.

Tested with spring-boot v2.0.5.RELEASE

Comment: This should definitely be the accepted solution, as it doesn't require any changes in the FreeMarker templates. Thank you so much @Ruslan!

Answer (score 0):

While rendering template, freemarker call TaglibFactory, which search for TLD in fours ways:

1. addTldLocationsFromClasspathTlds
2. addTldLocationsFromWebXml
3. addTldLocationsFromWebInfTlds
4. addTldLocationsFromMetaInfTlds

All of these methods are in TablibFactory class at freemarker jar. That last one, scan every jar in WEB-INF/lib searching for /META-INF/**/*.tld. You can see this logging if debug mode for freemarker is enabled.

Take a look how your project is deployed. In my case, using eclipse, wtp, tomcat and maven, the maven dependencies was configured in Eclipse/Deployment assembly as maven dependencies, of course :), hence these libs are not in WEB-INF/lib and so, was not found by `addTldLocationsFromMetaInfTlds`.

A way to solve is forcing deployment to copy all maven dependencies to WEB-INF/lib. I did it opening server configuration, at eclipse view 'servers', under server options uncheck all checkboxes but 'Module auto reload by default'.

Answer (score 0):

None of those solutions worked for me, but after analysing the workarounds in the [original ticket](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/907) I found a solution that does work:

1 - Add the following in the pom.xml

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

2 - Create the following classes

2.1 ClassPathTldsLoader

```
import org.apache.commons.lang3.ArrayUtils;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.freemarker.FreeMarkerConfigurer;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class ClassPathTldsLoader  {

    private static final String SECURITY_TLD = "/META-INF/security.tld";

    final private List<String> classPathTlds;

    public ClassPathTldsLoader(String... classPathTlds) {
        super();
        if(ArrayUtils.isEmpty(classPathTlds)){
            this.classPathTlds = Arrays.asList(SECURITY_TLD);
        }else{
            this.classPathTlds = Arrays.asList(classPathTlds);
        }
    }

    @Autowired
    private FreeMarkerConfigurer freeMarkerConfigurer;

    @PostConstruct
    public void loadClassPathTlds() {
        freeMarkerConfigurer.getTaglibFactory().setClasspathTlds(classPathTlds);
    }


}
```

2.2 FreemarkerTaglibsConfig

```
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.ConditionalOnMissingBean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
public class FreemarkerTaglibsConfig {


    @Bean
    @ConditionalOnMissingBean(ClassPathTldsLoader.class)
    public ClassPathTldsLoader classPathTldsLoader(){
        return new ClassPathTldsLoader();
    }

}
```

3 - Now you can load in ftl files, for example, security libs

```
<#assign spring = JspTaglibs["http://www.springframework.org/security/tags"]>
```

I hope this is useful for somebody else.