# Freemarker can't find JSP tld-s

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc, tomcat, freemarker

I am creating a project with tomcat 7, spring 4.1.7 (with spring mvc) and freemarker 2.3.23. All libs are deployed under /WEB-INF/lib which contains custom libs with tlds under their own /META-INF/.

But when freemarker scans the <#assign a=JspTagLib["/WEB-INF/a.tld"]>, system complains it can't find this definition file.

After debugging into freemarker's TaglibFacotry.java, I found the explicitly mapped tld location is not working. That means you have to put tlds directly under class path. I tried to copy over one tld to /WEB-INF/, it works.

Further investigation shows "servletContext.getResourcePaths("/WEB-INF/lib")" always returns null value.

Did I miss some configurations? Or is it related with compatibility problem since it works fine with Jetty?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think your question boils down to a Tomcat/Servlet question: Why does `servletContext.getResourcePaths("/WEB-INF/lib")` return `null` despite you have a such directory? So totally independently of FreeMarker, could you try what does `servletContext.getResourcePaths("/WEB-INF/lib")` return and then if what does `servletContext.getResourcePaths("/WEB-INF/lib/")` return? (I suspect Tomcat 7 is particular about the trailing `/`.)

Comment: Thanks @ddekany for replying. No luck with the tailing /.

Answer (score 0):

Verify if your deployment is copying all jars to WEB-INF/lib. TaglibFactory scans every jar inside there searching for /META-INF/**/*tlds.

Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/37092269/1113510