# Disable Freemarker Debug Messages

Tags: spring-boot, freemarker

I have a spring boot application, and I am unable to disable the log messages from Freemarker. I have [read the documentation](https://docs.huihoo.com/freemarker/2.3.20/pgui_misc_logging.html) and also perform multiple attempts based on internet search, but somehow I  can't find how to disable and I am currently very frustrated.

Whenever I load any page in my spring boot application, freemarker displays dozens of log messages such as

```
[...]
216 [http-nio-8111-exec-2] DEBUG freemarker.cache  - TemplateLoader.findTemplateSource("spring_en_AU.ftl"): Not found
216 [http-nio-8111-exec-2] DEBUG freemarker.cache  - TemplateLoader.findTemplateSource("spring_en_AU.ftl"): Not found
217 [http-nio-8111-exec-2] DEBUG freemarker.cache  - TemplateLoader.findTemplateSource("spring_en.ftl"): Not found
217 [http-nio-8111-exec-2] DEBUG freemarker.cache  - TemplateLoader.findTemplateSource("spring_en.ftl"): Not found
218 [http-nio-8111-exec-2] DEBUG freemarker.cache  - TemplateLoader.findTemplateSource("spring.ftl"): Found
218 [http-nio-8111-exec-2] DEBUG freemarker.cache  - TemplateLoader.findTemplateSource("spring.ftl"): Found
[...]
```

How can I disable those DEBUG messages ?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: Adding pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>my.group</groupId>
    <artifactId>monitoring</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>monitoring</name>
    <description></description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>14</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-freemarker</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <!-- Setup Spring Data common components -->
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-commons</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <!-- Setup Spring Data JPA Repository support -->
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <!--spring security login with google and/or facebook-->
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <!--spring security login with google and/or facebook-->
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-jose</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <!--access to JPA postgres arrays-->
            <groupId>com.vladmihalcea</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-types-52</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <!--csrf-->
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <!--allows hot swap https://dzone.com/articles/spring-boot-application-live-reload-hot-swap-with -->
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>4.5.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
            <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
            <version>2.10.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.twilio.sdk</groupId>
            <artifactId>twilio</artifactId>
            <version>7.55.2</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <!--https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33755964/spring-boot-with-jsp-categoryGroup-libs-in-embedded-tomcat/56095625#56095625-->
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <!--https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33755964/spring-boot-with-jsp-categoryGroup-libs-in-embedded-tomcat/56095625#56095625-->
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.github.dfabulich/sitemapgen4j -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.dfabulich</groupId>
            <artifactId>sitemapgen4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.dinstone</groupId>
            <artifactId>beanstalkc</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.minidev</groupId>
            <artifactId>asm</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.minidev</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-smart</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.drewnoakes</groupId>
            <artifactId>metadata-extractor</artifactId>
            <version>2.14.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.imgscalr</groupId>
            <artifactId>imgscalr-lib</artifactId>
            <version>4.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>RELEASE</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>${artifactId}</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: Can you share your POM file please?

Comment: @TechGeek added POM file

Comment: Can you follow this link https://mkyong.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-test-how-to-stop-debug-logs/

Comment: Can you endorse the answer. So everyone aware of it

Comment: @TechGeek I have been to quick. On further usage, no effect. I mistake that some debug messages when the app loaded were removed (which makes sense) but when you open any page the "freemarler.cache" stills being displayed. Will remove previous comment.